# Add a list of DTOs to the master DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

I have two DTOs:

```
public class MasterDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DetailDTO> Details { get; set; }
}

public class DetailDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DetailName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have a function:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var r = context.MasterData
                   .Select(d => new MasterDTO
                   {
                       Id = d.Id,
                       Name = d.Name,
                   }
}
```

I need to fill the list of DetailDTOs too and do it in a single request.

At this moment, I have to get list of DetailsData data and add it through **foreach** to the MasterDTO, which, of course causes a lot of requests to the database server.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you have your foreign key relationships set up in the DB? If you do, the context can automatically populate detail data for you.

Comment: @BobHorn Fancy running into you here!

Comment: @JefferyKhan LOL. I know! I went to your profile page, but it was hard to tell if that was really you. The spelling of your name gave it away. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your data call, do an eager load on your DetailData.
Example:

`var r = context.MasterData.Include("DetailData")`

**DetailData** should be the name of your navigation property attached to your `MasterData` entity.

This will cause detail data to be pulled along with your call for `MasterData`.

The full call may look something like this:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    context.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var r = context.MasterData.Include("DetailData")
        .Select(d => new MasterDTO()
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            Name = d.Name,
            Details = d.Details.Select(dt => new DetailDTO()
            {
                Id = dt.Id,
                DetailName = dt.DetailName
            })
        });
}
```

Comment: it will load the entire object, instead I need to "pick" only **Id** and **Name**

Comment: I've included how to disable lazy loading so it will only pull what you tell it to.

Comment: +1 because this answers the question. You have to be careful though. If this is in your data layer, then this is not where you want to be worrying about what goes in a DTO to be passed to a view. This couples the data layer to the view. If this is a non-trivial app, you'd be better off including full objects, then doing your DTO mapping at the service layer.